# Testing a Mac-developed WebApp with IE through Virtualization?

Tags: internet-explorer, macos, debugging, web-applications, virtual-machine

I'm currently developing a Java-based web application on my MacBook. Most of my testing is on Firefox and Safari, but some clients have expressed interest in using the app on Internet Explorer with WinXP and Vista.

I know I'll have some serious client-side / Ajax debugging, adjustements to do.
I do have a Fusion guest with WinXP on it and IE6.

Question is: when I run my app on the host (Mac), say it's listening at http://localhost:8080/myApp, how do I access it from within the WinXP guest VM?

Thanks,
Rollo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up your System Preferences on the Mac side. Network. Get the IP address of your computer. Try that IP instead of `localhost`.

This is a duplicate of [How Do I Access The Host Machine From The Guest Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449/how-do-i-access-the-host-from-vmware-fusion)