# How to get a browser inside VMware fusion get access to a GAE-SDK-based page on the host machine?

Tags: google-app-engine, vmware

I've got VMWare Fusion (2.0.6) running on my mac osx10.6.2.  I've also got the GAE (python) SDK on the mac, operating on port 8082. I'd like to be able to view my GAE pages in the SDK from the windows image, without uploading the app somewhere.

I've got tomcat installed on the mac; macname:8080 works (with required "http://") to access the basic tomcat page.  But macname:8082 gives me a "page cannot be displayed" error.  localhost:8082 from the mac loads the page/app just fine, thanks.

I've perused [How Do I Access The Host From VMware Fusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449/how-do-i-access-the-host-from-vmware-fusion); none of those solutions work (though the macname:8080 solution is the closest).

Help? Thoughts?

Thanks,
LH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may need to use the --address parameter to the development server as described in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html:

*--address=...
The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the development server from another computer on your network. An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both localhost access and hostname access. Default is localhost.*

I believe that if you do dev_appserver.py --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8082 yourapp\
then you should be able to get to it from inside your virtual machine as macname:8082

I apologize that I am not able to test this before posting, but I do hope that it helps.