# trouble accessing localhost from ie7 running on parallels (win xp) on mac os x

Tags: parallels

I'm running the app engine devserver on localhost:8080, and want to access it from ie7 running on parallels.

I've tried all of the tips here:
[How Do I Access The Host Machine From The Guest Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449/how-do-i-access-the-host-from-vmware-fusion)

And they seem like they should work, particularly accessing via the gateway ip address.  I've also

`sudo ipfw add allow tcp from 8080 to 8089`

for good measure.  Still no dice.  I can access the external internet from ie7. The connection settings on parallels are set to 'Shared networking'.  I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not by any chance running it on localhost/127.0.0.1 on OS X and are trying to get at it using localhost/127.0.0.1 from XP?

If so, that's likely to be your problem - I would seriously doubt that the two instances of the OS share the loopback interface as that's specific to the OS.

I'd run it on OS X using the local IP and not localhost, then use the IP address to access it from XP. This should work if the XP box can see the host.

Comment: I'm using localhost on os X, and was trying to access it on windows using the gateway interface (not localhost).  

that said, running the local server on the ip address did the trick, thanks!  Now the only issue will be if I'm developing offline.

Comment: @Karl R - continuing to usw localhost if you're only working on OS X will work fine. It's only when you're testing from Windows that you need to run the server on a real IP address to make it visible to the outside - which includes Windows in this case, even if it's "inside".

Comment: it does seem like others have gotten accessing 'localhost' of the hosting computer from a VM to work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449/how-do-i-access-the-host-from-vmware-fusion